# How to modify specific blocks in an Azure Block Blob with the Python API?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

The [Azure documentation on block blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-block-blobs) describes that it is possible to:

> You can modify an existing block blob by inserting, replacing, or deleting existing blocks.

However, looking at the Python API documentation of the [`ContainerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python) class, the only related method seems to be [`ContainerClient.upload_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-upload-blob), and it doesn't look like it offers the functionality of inserting or replacing specific blocks inside a block blob via their block ID.

Is there any other way to operate on the *block* level of a block blob with the Python SDK, or is this only possible by using the REST API manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods you are looking for are [`stage_block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-stage-block) for uploading blocks, [`get_block_list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-get-block-list) to get the list of blocks already uploaded and [`commit_block_list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-commit-block-list) to commit the blocks. These methods are available in [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python) class.

Comment: So the key step on container level is to actually use [`ContainerClient.get_blob_client`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-get-blob-client) to have access to the low-level API.

Comment: That is correct. While .Net SDK has special classes to deal with different kinds of blobs, everything is put in one class (BlobClient) in Python SDK.